# Multiple routes under same tree in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am having problem while implementing Multiple routes as defined Below in my snippet

EDIT: i am getting this exception too 
**Additional information:
Zend\Mvc\Exception\InvalidControllerException**

with Message

**Controller of type Account\Controller\VoucherController is invalid; must implement Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface**

```
<?php
namespace Account;
 return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Account\Controller\Account' => 'Account\Controller\AccountController',
        'Account\Controller\Voucher' => 'Account\Controller\VoucherController',
    ),
    // --------- Doctrine Settings For the Module
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            'account_entities' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Account/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    'Account\Entity' => 'account_entities'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'account' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/account[/][:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Account\Controller\Account',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'voucher' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/account/voucher[/][:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Account\Controller\Voucher',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'account' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

Now the issue is i am getting a 404, when i try to access **MyHost/account/Voucher**
P.S: I already have A Controller under Account/Controller/Voucher and a view under Account/View/Voucher named as **index.phtml** now i dont know what am i missing here.

Comment: The error message `Controller of type Account\Controller\VoucherController is invalid; must implement Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface` says that your controller wrong.  It must implmeent DispatchableInterface (which it will, if it extends ActionController, etc).  If you can't figure it out, please edit your question and show your controller code.

Comment: please post your controller code. seems like an issue with the controller class rather than your routes.

Comment: @timdev You are correct, i had issue with implementing AbstractInterfaceController. Which i didnt implemented,  if you can ans it, i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adnrew and Timdev comments above that there is something not right in your controller, you can check few basic things in your controller, that you have following code correct. specially the typos.

```
namespace Account\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;



class VoucherController extends AbstractActionController {

// you acctions


}
```

Comment: very true i am marking this correct for time being, as i assumed Timedev answered it 1st, but as comment